# Automatically Execute C# Application when new sms receive in modem

Tags: sms, autoload, gsm, modem

I am trying to develop an application that will communicate with the GSM modem. I have done all the setup correctly, but when I will deployed this application to server than my question raises.

I want that whenever an SMS message is received in the modem, it automatically updates a list that is shown in the C# application. What should I do and how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use AT commands/Windows Mobile Broadband API/Win 8 non-Metro API to read the SMS from the modem, and then you can do what you like with it.

Standard GSM AT commands are defined in the specification 3GPP TS 27.007, which you can download from www.3gpp.org.